# Get the properties of reference pages - Kentico

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I have a page where I need to display testimonials, In that page document type I have a field to assign testimonials by using page selection, so It will save the GUID of selected testimonial in the database,

I have used following code to display the description of Testimonial, But is there any other way to get the document fileds by passing the GUID,

One option I can use is write a custom macro.

```
{% Documents["/Page-Resource/Testimonial/Testimonial"].getValue("Description") #%}
```

Note: I have used the text/xml type transformation

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not that easy but there is one way and that is to use loops:

```
r = ""; foreach (i in CMSContext.Current.Documents) {if(i.NodeGUID == "a88f82be-bb76-4b82-8faf-5253209f0f75"){r = i}}; r.Description
```

Notes:

1. Use NodeGUID or DocumentGUID based on what you store in your custom field.
2. Replace the hardcoded guid with something like `CMSContext.Current.CurrentDocument.YourDescriptionFieldWithGuid`
3. See the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Macro+syntax#Macrosyntax-Iteration(loops)) if you have any doubts about K# syntax